# Comparing two ids to get the lower

Tags: java, functional-programming

Im trying to compare two ids to get the lower in ascii.
The ids are alphanumeric `"836778436K"`, `"K8474874"`....

I tried with

```java
lowerSupplyDeliveryTerm.stream()
                       .map(dto -> dto.provider.nif)
                       .min(SupplyDto::provider.nif)
```

The `SupplyDto` class is

```java
public class SupplyDto {
    public String id;
    public long version;

    public SupplierProviderDto provider = new SupplierProviderDto();
    public SuppliedSparePartDto sparePart = new SuppliedSparePartDto();

    public double price;
    public int deliveryTerm;

    public static class SupplierProviderDto {
        public String id;
        public String nif;
        public String name;

    }

    public static class SuppliedSparePartDto {
        public String id;
        public String code;
        public String description;

    }

}
```

The problem is that I don't know which lambda function should I introduce in the min function to compare the nifs of the providers in the dto.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the SupplyDto with the lowest ID, or the lowest ID itself? Depending on that, you should either use `map` and then just `min`, or `min` with comparator but no map, but not both.

Comment: Check out the documentation of [`String#compareTo(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)).

Comment: @tobias_k i want the lowest id not the supplyDto. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a minimal `ID` of a nested object, you could have written as follows:

```java
lowerSupplyDeliveryTerm.stream()
                       .map(dto -> dto.provider.nif)
                       .min(String::compareTo) // Optional<String> is returned here
                       .orElse("No minimal nif found")
```

If you need to get ID of the DTO with minimal nif:

```java
lowerSupplyDeliveryTerm.stream()
                       .min(Comparator.comparing(dto -> dto.provider.inf))
                       .map(dto -> dto.provider.id)
                       .orElse("No ID for minimal nif found")
```

Comment: I am really grateful to you, i was really stucked. Many Thanks for your help =D.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the lowest ID, you do not have to use any special lambda for the `min` comparator. You can just use `Comparator.naturalOrder()` to get the `min` element according the the elements' own `compareTo` method.

```
String minId = lowerSupplyDeliveryTerm.stream()
                       .map(dto -> dto.provider.nif)
                       .min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
```

Comment: I am really grateful to you, you have helped me a lot. Many thanks